# multi virtual serial ports does not refresh the received data

Tags: c#, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I have a serial port listening console application that i developed in c# and everything was working fine.

But in recent days, the received data is not changed however actually the received data is changed (i can check from the monitor or when restart my application). The port always keeps write the same data as received string. But it refreshes the data when I restart my application. I mean serial port doesn not refresh/update received data on change.

My application was working fine before we set FIFO property to TRUE. There was no problem when the port settings were FALSE.

This is a weighbridge application and there are 20 weighbridges at the field. Each of them sends data to my server via virtual ports. (COM1....COM20)

Any idea? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't see a 'FIFO' property in the SerialPort class. Is it in the driver? If it worked with it set to False why did you change it? No code and my internet telepathy is down.

Comment: Hi dbasnett, we had to change it because of multiplexter circuit box which sends the data needed this FIFO enabled.For this condition i have to update my c# codes again to be able to let application to run in FIFO enabled mode.

Comment: is not there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

FIFO is the interrupt used only by the serial port. You should not used it. Kindly refer to the following link.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-4.html

Cant you do without the FIFO setting?